# PHP foreach of a multidimensional array using recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am using a recursive function to create a comment/reply system as yt or fb is using. I've done the function, but I cannot figure it out how to make the `foreach` function if I don't know for sure how many branches the array will have.

```
$coments = $this->mu_model->getByWhereStmt('comments', 'article_id', $article->id);
$comments = array();
    $comm = array();
    foreach($coments as $coment) {
        if($coment->reply_to_msg_id == 0) {
            $comm = array(
                'id' => $coment->id,
                'sender_id' => $coment->sender_id,
                'message' => $coment->message,
                'article_id' => $coment->article_id,
                'like' => $coment->like,
                'reply_to' => $coment->reply_to_msg_id,
                'added_date' => $coment->added_date,
                'deleted' => $coment->deleted,
                );
            $reply_id = $coment->id;
            if(!empty(reply_msg($reply_id, $coments))) {
                $repliess = reply_msg($reply_id, $coments);
                array_push($comm, $repliess);
            }
            array_push($comments, $comm);
        }
    }

function reply_msg($reply_id, $coments) {
        $replies = array();
        $reply = array();
        foreach($coments as $r_comment) {
            if($r_comment->reply_to_msg_id != 0) {
                if($r_comment->reply_to_msg_id == $reply_id) {  
                    $reply = array(
                            'id' => $r_comment->id,
                            'sender_id' => $r_comment->sender_id,
                            'message' => $r_comment->message,
                            'article_id' => $r_comment->article_id,
                            'like' => $r_comment->like,
                            'reply_to' => $r_comment->reply_to_msg_id,
                            'added_date' => $r_comment->added_date,
                            'deleted' => $r_comment->deleted,
                        );
                    if(!empty(reply_msg($r_comment->id, $coments))) {
                        $repli = reply_msg($r_comment->id, $coments);
                        array_push($reply, $repli);
                    }
                    array_push($replies, $reply);
                }
            }
        }
        return $replies;
```

Here is an example:
http://i58.tinypic.com/118f8tt.png

Comment: Post your code here, not as an image.

Comment: and post the code aswell, not just the data structure

Comment: Hi, you need to show us some code that you've tried, and explain specifically where you got stuck. At the moment, this appears to be a request for other people to write your code for you, which is not the purpose of this site.

Comment: I posted the code as well.

Comment: Write a mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
function process($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
        // Process the content of the array
    }
    if (isset($array[8])) // If we have linked arrays
        foreach($array[8] as $subArray)
            process($subArray);
}
```

PS: I would also set a key for the linked arrays, like 'children' or 'subcomments'. In this way you could call `isset($array['children'])` and so on, which is more maintainable than accesing the array by its index.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and for understanding my question!